# Not able to create docker image of keystonejs because it contains lot of package.json and packages inside it

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, keystonejs, keystonejs6

I am trying to create docker image of this official public repo of **keystonejs** https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone

But it contains lot of packages inside it and each package contains package.json inside it, it is some short of **multi-module** project.

the **package.json** is present in root directory as well as in sub directory.

how can we create **docker** image containing all these packages ? if anyone has worked on keystonejs please help me on this ?

thank you

Comment: You are interested only in *package.json* in project root directory, remaining are dependencies generated automatically

Answer (score 0):

The [Keystone codebase](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone) is indeed "some sort of multi-module project" – it's what's called a **monorepo**.

Generally, the term "monorepo" refers to a collection of source code from different projects, stored together in a single repository, inside a version control system (like `git` for example). They're fairly common for large projects:

> Google, Facebook, Microsoft, Uber, Airbnb, and Twitter all employ very large monorepos with varying strategies to scale build systems and version control software with a large volume of code and daily changes.
> — [Wikipedia: Monorepos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monorepo)

In the NodeJS ecosystem "monorepo" often refers to a repo that includes code for multiple npm packages.

In Keystone case, the main repo includes several npm packages (in the [packages](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/main/packages) dir), a bunch of tests, the Keystone marketing and docs websites (in [docs](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/main/docs)), and various other bits and pieces.

Thinkmill, the team that builds Keystone, has a guide on the [monorepo patterns and tools](https://monorepo.guide) they use. A Google search will give you plenty of other takes; it's a popular topic.

> How can we create docker image containing all these packages?

If you want to deploy a Keystone app using docker you don't need to mess with the Keystone repo itself. You just want to install Keystone as a dependency, like any other npm package. The steps are basically:

1. Create a project in your own repo
2. Pull the [core Keystone npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@keystone-6/core) (`@keystone-6/core`) in as a dependancy, then..
3. Add a `dockerfile` that builds and runs the app

Getting a Keystone project running is actually super easy – it only take a few files. There's even a tool called `create-keystone-app` that sets them up for you. I'd suggest running thought the [Getting Started guide](https://keystonejs.com/docs/walkthroughs/getting-started-with-create-keystone-app) to get a simple app running locally, then write your `dockerfile` there.